# How to auto generate Contract Tests from an Open Api spec

Tags: testing, automated-tests, karate

As a tester, I have been provided with an Open Api spec that is subject to change.  I'd like a way to automate the required Contract tests as much as possible.  Is there a utility out there that will do that?  That is suck in an Api spec and spit out a suggested set of contract tests.  We use Karate Api but I'd settle for anything that was able to generate a set of Contract tests with minimal manual intervention.

Comment: dev of Karate here - IMO the info in an OAS file is insufficient to generate test work-flows. the IDE plugins for Karate (commercial) can generate a bunch of Karate HTTP calls from a spec, but it still requires a fair bit of massaging by hand to create a working test. I consider what you ask not possible ( and also not useful, refer this article for why: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/api-contract-testing-visual-guide-peter-thomas ) - if you do find something you find useful, do share ;)